# Java, error while connecting via SSL (Remote host closed connection during handshake)

Tags: java, android, ssl

everyone. 
I need to connect to the server using server and client certificates. I'm using following code:
(ported form android)

```
private HttpsURLConnection getHttpsURLConnection(URL url, String certAlias)
        throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, java.security.cert.CertificateException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    CertificateFactory certFactory = null;
    java.security.cert.Certificate cert = null;
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = null;
    SSLContext sslContext = null;

    //load client cert
    final KeyStore clientKS = getClientKeyStore();
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(keyStore, clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray());

    // Load certificates from an InputStream
    certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    InputStream servCertIS = new FileInputStream(caCertificateName);
    cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(servCertIS);

    // Create a KeyStore containing the trusted certificates
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certAlias, cert);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the certificates in our KeyStore
    tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init(keyStore);
    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream(); //error!
    //peoccess inputStream here.

    return connection;
```

I've enabled debug property for ssl and handshake and got the following output:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
Server Nonce:
Master Secret:
Client MAC write Secret:
Server MAC write Secret:
Client write key:
Server write key:
Client write IV:
Server write IV:

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 104, 160, 185, 140, 237, 61, 94, 119, 119, 68, 101, 52 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at testClient1.getHttpsURLConnection(testClient1.java:86)
    at testClient1.getClient(testClient1.java:106)
    at testClient1.main(testClient1.java:134)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

I'm getting this error on android device and on desktop java. But I can freely connect to the server with the webbrowser using this client certificate.

Maybe it's important or not
Url for the server is: https://icon.sbrf.ru:9443 ( note the port)
also client certificate is with cyrillic name in it(I don't know is that matter, but there are often troubles about cyrillic symbols).

**UPDATE**

Here is CertificateRequest

```
    *** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=ICONDP, OU=00CA, O=Savings Bank of the Russian Federation, L=RU, ST=Moscow>
<CN=SberBank External CA, O=sberbank, C=ru>
<CN=icon.sbrf.ru, OU=00CA, O=Savings Bank of the Russian Federation, C=RU>
<CN=Sberbank Enterprise CA, O=Sberbank, C=RU>
<CN=tv-icon01.sigma.sbrf.ru, OU=00CA, O=Savings Bank of the Russian Federation, C=RU>
<CN=TV-ICON01.sigma.sbrf.ru, OU=Root Certificate, OU=TV-ICON01Cell01, OU=TV-ICON01CellManager01, O=IBM, C=US>
<CN=Sberbank Root CA, O=Sberbank, C=RU>
<CN=Sberbank Test CA, O=Sberbank, C=RU>
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 AC CE 4B 71 A4 A6   45 94 75 D8 B5 80 AE DA  ....Kq..E.u.....
0010: D3 01 0D 6F FA 1F 6F E4   F8 4C 47 7A EE 48 A6 02  ...o..o..LGz.H..
0020: 21 9F 79 6E 61 AE B0 DA   29 F0 97 B4 FD 0A 41 88  !.yna...).....A.
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 53 D6 17 36 80 81 C3 3B   16 E5 60 3E 29 B3 86 68  S..6...;..`>)..h
0010: F2 CA 49 13 87 19 98 A0   0C 88 88 FE 03 95 F6 91  ..I.............
Server Nonce:
0000: 53 D6 17 31 BA B0 DB E0   0A E2 7E 07 CF 04 C9 F9  S..1............
0010: 17 EA F1 F6 A5 C3 20 50   8D 3C 72 8F 42 57 DF 51  ...... P.<r.BW.Q
Master Secret:
0000: 92 49 CF 65 F3 64 26 CF   54 5F 78 2F 83 4E D2 4A  .I.e.d&.T_x/.N.J
0010: 20 E0 E0 AE CC 5F F8 6B   09 4E 2F E6 A8 01 94 10   ...._.k.N/.....
0020: 35 7B BD 2B A7 43 2E D2   4C 0F B1 F6 3C 6B 1E 08  5..+.C..L...<k..
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 87 04 6A 37 DD 7F B6 D6   AA 31 FE 10 C8 0E B0 71  ..j7.....1.....q
0010: 16 6F 72 AF                                        .or.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: C7 64 75 F7 E2 67 2C 8F   DF 14 6C 5E 7E 01 8A C1  .du..g,...l^....
0010: A0 8B E4 C4                                        ....
Client write key:
0000: 3E CE F3 FC B1 B0 C7 E2   6C F1 20 68 36 39 A5 E5  >.......l. h69..
Server write key:
0000: 26 C8 9F 98 DE 58 D3 0E   A1 25 38 05 4E E7 25 DF  &....X...%8.N.%.
Client write IV:
0000: 0C CE 33 F3 1C 00 C1 5B   3F 75 F7 EF EB AA 16 69  ..3....[?u.....i
Server write IV:
0000: 1A 18 D6 B1 32 23 5D 26   24 26 96 BC 42 1F 27 A2  ....2#]&$&..B.'.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 228, 62, 93, 239, 222, 236, 155, 56, 146, 50, 189, 117 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
main, called closeSocket()
```

Certificate chain is really empty, and I cannot figure why, cause I'm using 100% working client certificate(I checked it via webbrowser).

There is a lot of another info, including certificate chain in logfile before this record, but I believe they are all about server certificate.

So, It seems that problem is somewhere in the certificate load code, but I don't know where

**UPDATE 2**

So, I've created a kesytore and import client certificate there converting it to jks.
Here is result of *keytool -list -keystore test.jks -v*

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: lp-32205b37-88a0-4d85-8c6a-4a18daa82dd0
Creation date: 28.07.2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: EMAILADDRESS=RONovoselov.SBT@sberbank.ru, CN=Новоселов Роман Олегович, OU=CA_Users, OU=CA, DC=sigma, DC=sbrf, DC=ru
Issuer: CN=SberBank External CA, O=sberbank, C=ru
Serial number: 4ccbdc23000000002851
Valid from: Wed Mar 07 16:55:00 MSK 2012 until: Fri Mar 07 17:05:00 MSK 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  A0:6F:EA:C6:16:34:8D:46:67:26:21:E0:C6:28:BC:63
     SHA1: 19:77:D8:62:44:49:08:89:0E:42:60:8E:64:D2:97:18:36:B5:BA:2D
     SHA256: D0:CF:86:FD:46:0F:29:E7:4A:26:AE:D5:63:5B:C8:41:1E:A8:D3:13:9E:EC:0D:BA:C6:8D:B1:D4:4D:21:2B:45
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.15 Criticality=false
0000: 30 35 30 0E 06 08 2A 86   48 86 F7 0D 03 02 02 02  050...*.H.......
0010: 00 80 30 0E 06 08 2A 86   48 86 F7 0D 03 04 02 02  ..0...*.H.......
0020: 00 80 30 07 06 05 2B 0E   03 02 07 30 0A 06 08 2A  ..0...+....0...*
0030: 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 07                               .H.....


#2: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
0000: 30 18 30 0A 06 08 2B 06   01 05 05 07 03 04 30 0A  0.0...+.......0.
0010: 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07   03 02                    ..+.......


#3: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
0000: 30 2F 06 27 2B 06 01 04   01 82 37 15 08 84 F3 D1  0/.'+.....7.....
0010: 3C 87 F2 87 61 87 BD 9B   02 83 AA B4 63 81 82 FA  <...a.......c...
0020: 35 81 2A 84 FB D4 1C 83   BD CB 49 02 01 64 02 01  5.*.......I..d..
0030: 17                                                 .


#4: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://pki.sberbank.ru/pki/aia/Cert01.sigma.sbrf.ru_SberBank%20External%20CA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=SberBank%20External%20CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=sigma,DC=sbrf,DC=ru?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://extpki.sigma.sbrf.ru/CertEnroll/Cert01.sigma.sbrf.ru_SberBank%20External%20CA.crt
]
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: DB F3 38 88 08 D3 25 A2   D6 3E 5A C2 28 6D 21 09  ..8...%..>Z.(m!.
0010: E7 2E 1E B3                                        ....
]
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://pki.sberbank.ru/pki/cdp/SberBank%20External%20CA.crl, URIName: ldap:///CN=SberBank%20External%20CA,CN=Cert01,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=sigma,DC=sbrf,DC=ru?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint, URIName: http://extpki.sigma.sbrf.ru/CertEnroll/SberBank%20External%20CA.crl]
]]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  emailProtection
  clientAuth
]

#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#9: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  Other-Name: Unrecognized ObjectIdentifier: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3
  RFC822Name: RONovoselov.SBT@sberbank.ru
]

#10: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 4C AB B5 F4 9B 7D FB 50   73 E0 CF EB AC 3D 00 5F  L......Ps....=._
0010: FE 82 32 9F                                        ..2.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: test
Creation date: 28.07.2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Aleksey Makarkin, OU=SBRF, O=SBRF, L=Moscow, ST=Moscow, C=RU
Issuer: CN=Aleksey Makarkin, OU=SBRF, O=SBRF, L=Moscow, ST=Moscow, C=RU
Serial number: 7f98a299
Valid from: Mon Jul 28 15:10:33 MSK 2014 until: Sun Oct 26 15:10:33 MSK 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  BC:51:FA:3B:6A:EB:4A:40:BC:87:53:DB:6D:E5:D7:59
     SHA1: 74:6B:08:92:0C:8D:57:34:CF:18:EC:6D:60:70:07:C2:07:E5:C5:00
     SHA256: DD:4D:C7:3E:0C:4F:25:1B:6F:07:76:98:C2:B4:C8:5D:C9:A8:9D:87:E5:8D:AE:12:26:8C:22:0C:89:1D:E3:02
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withDSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 06 F5 F7 A7 83 44 FC 9C   F2 70 6B EC 04 E8 03 3E  .....D...pk....>
0010: C4 B5 A0 FC                                        ....
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve this problem.

At first I had a stupid typo in code

```
final KeyStore clientKS = getClientKeyStore(); //save client certificate in one keyStore
...
kmf.init(keyStore, clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray()); //load into another( use if for server certificate lately)
```

At second, seems that certificate I'm using is deprecated

```
Valid from: Wed Mar 07 16:55:00 MSK 2012 until: Fri Mar 07 17:05:00 MSK 2014
```

For some reason, Chrome web browser is ignoring this, but JVM(?) -not. I dunno how is it possible, but this is observed behaviour.

Thanks @EJP for support

Comment: Could you post the entire solution? I'm trying to crawl a website and it doesn't work. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake.

Answer (score 1):

The server asked for a client certificate and you didn't send one, so it closed the connection.

Either you don't have a client certificate at all, or at least you don't have one that's trusted by the server. You can see the signers the server trusts in the CertificateRequest message immediately before your trace starts.

Comment: I have correct client certificate, and I can connect with it via any webbrowser. (I suppose it means that certificate is correct).  So, I make a conclusion that there is an error in my code, but where?

Comment: The empty certificate chain message proves my point. Show us the CertificateRequest message and the certificate chain of your certificate. Edit them into your question.

Comment: So you don't have a certificate that was signed by anybody named in the CertificateRequest, as I already said. What does 'keytool -list -v' say about the issuer of your certificate?

Comment: HI, again. Issuer of the client certificate is "Issuer: CN=SberBank External CA, O=sberbank, C=ru", the one that is listed in certificate request